# Keyboard input to a serial console redirected to telnet

Tags: vmware, telnet, socat, cisco

I'm trying to install a Cisco Nexus 9000v VM on VMWare Workstation on a Linux machine. That's how far I got:

After importing the .ova file I set up a serial console in the VM settings whereby I chose "Use socket" and specified /tmp/serial0 as such. Then I booted up the vm and redirected the traffic from /tmp/serial0 to telnet with socat. I connected via telnet (also tried PuTTy) and got to the basic setup procedure of the Nexus 9000v. So far so good. My problem now is: when I try to set the admin password the confirmation seems to get transferred immediately after without any further input - it says "Admin password confirmation failed. Please try again" right away.

So my question is: what's happening here and how can I get the password set anyway?